# WordPress REST API endpoint doesn't respond

Tags: php, json, wordpress, http-post, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a custom payment plugin now I need to set up an endpoint that will receive webhook callbacks from the payment gateway. My code for the endpoint is as seen below:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route(
      'namespace/v1/', 'endpoint',
       array (
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'return_payment_status'
      )
  );
});

function return_payment_status (WP_REST_Request $request_data) {
    $pay_resp = array();
    
    $params = $request_data->get_params();
    
    if ( isset($params['result']) ) {
        $pay_resp['result'] = $params['result'];
        $pay_resp['message'] = $params['message'];
    }
    else {
        $pay_resp['result'] = 'Payment failed';
        $pay_resp['message'] = $params['message'];
    }
    return $pay_resp;
}
```

Now when I try the endpoint in POSTMAN and send data I get the following response:

> { "result":"Payment failed", "message":null }

Which seems that no data is being sent to the endpoint. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What does `error_log(print_r($params, true));` output in your [debug.log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) file?

Comment: I've set ('WP_DEBUG', true) but I can't see the debug.log file in my wp-content folder.

Comment: I tried setting headers with key-value pair "Content-Type", "application-json" in Postman and it worked. Now the gateway I'm using doesn't define such header information when I receive the callback. Is there a way to fix it through my code?